# Php form creates many empty lines associates with js event handler

Tags: javascript, php, database, forms

I created a php form that works well.
BUT, (yes there is always a BUT) I handle the submit event to call a link that insert datas in another database.

When Js run, my form creates a lot of empty lines in my personal database. I don't understand why.

I give you my code :

PHP :

```
public function displayForm() {

    $output =   '<div id="form-popup-newsletter">
                    <center>                        
                        <form id="nl_form" method="post">
                            <legend>Abonne-toi à la Newsletter<span id="cross-close">X</span></legend>                          
                            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                              <label class="btn btn-primary">
                                <input id="civility" type="radio" name="civility" value="madame"> Madame
                              </label>
                              <label class="btn btn-primary">
                                <input id="civility" type="radio" name="civility" value="monsieur"> Monsieur
                              </label>
                            </div>                          
                            <div>
                                <label for="surname">Prenom</label>
                                <input id="surname" type="text" name="surname" value="Surname" />
                                <span id="w-surname"></span>
                            </div>                          
                            <div>
                                <label for="name">Nom</label>                           
                                <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="Name"/>
                                <span id="w-name"></span>                          
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label for="birthdate">Date de Naissance</label>                            
                                <input id="birthdate" type="date" name="birthdate" value="Date de naissance"/>
                                <span id="w-birthdate"></span>                         
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label for="mail">Email</label>                         
                                <input id="mail" type="email" name="mail" value="Email"/>
                                <span id="w-mail"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label for="postal_code">Code Postal</label>                            
                                <input id="postal_code" type="number" name="postal_code" value="Code Postal"/>
                                <span id="w-postal_code"></span>
                            </div>                       
                            <input id="#submitform" type="submit" name="submitform" value="Sauvegarder" class="btn btn-danger" />                           </form>
                    </center>
                </div>';

    $objForm = new CustomForm;

    if ( isset( $_POST['submitform'] ) ) {

        if (isset($_POST['civility'])) {

            $objForm->civility  = $_POST['civility'];

        }

        $objForm->surname       = $_POST['surname'];
        $objForm->name          = $_POST['name'];
        $objForm->birthdate     = $_POST['birthdate'];
        $objForm->mail          = $_POST['mail'];
        $objForm->postal_code   = $_POST['postal_code'];
    }

    $this->fillDB($objForm);

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'output'          => $output
    ));
}
```

Javascript :

```
 $("#nl_form").submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var civility = $('#civility').val();
    var surname = $('#surname').val();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var birthdate = $('#birthdate').val();
    var mail = $('#mail').val();
    var postal_code = $('#postal_code').val();

    window.open("http://mylink.com/register.php?inp_46="+civility+"&inp_1="+surname+"&inp_2="+name+"&inp_4="+birthdate+"&inp_3="+mail+"&inp_13="+postal_code+"");

    return true;
});
```

Best.

Comment: Why do you need the javascript part?

Comment: To call my link that inserts datas in a extern database.

It's the first time i try to do something like that. So i don't understand every behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a link with window.open then you make a HTTP GET Request. So you have to use $_GET[...] to get the value of your parameters. E.g. for surname $_GET["inp_1"].

But don't use window.open for that instate make a Ajax request.

Here some usefull links

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started
- http://jquery.com/ http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check your links. 

Really useful.

Comment: Hi,

I tried with an ajax request this morning, and this works well.     I can send my variables to my two DB with no problem.     
Thanks you for your great help !